# select2 4.0 remote data is not selected after form reloading

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-select2

I have some troubles in select2 after migration from 3.5 version to 4.0.3 version.

I have a form with input:

```
  <div class="form-group ">
      <label class="control-label" for="equipment">Address of equipment</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="equipment" name="equipment"></select>        
  </div>
```

and have a js code:

```
        $("#equipment").select2({
            minimumInputLength: 2,
            ajax: {
                type: 'GET',
                url: options.equipmentsURL,
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        q: params.term // search term
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (data, page) {
                    var objects = data.objects;
                    var results = [];
                    for (var i=0; i < objects.length; i++){
                        var text = objects[i]['__str__'];
                        results.push({'id': objects[i].id, 'text': text});
                    }
                    return {results:results};
                }
            },

        });
```

Ajax loading works fine but if user would choose some option and reload the form(refresh the browser or make some errors in form) the selected option will be reseted. To avoid this problem in 3.5 version i get selected value from input:

```
 $('equipment').val();
```

and intialize select2 usinig initSelection callback.
In 4.0 version i could not find where to get selected value, **select input** has no options after reload.